# Picking parameters such that the limit goes towards 1.

Tags: calculus, limits, parametric

I have the below term and would like to pick the parameter $p$, such that the limit as $x\to\infty$ goes towards 1. We know that $k > 0$

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\log^3(x) + \log(x)x^{p} - \log^2(x)x^k \to 1$.

I have tried factoring $\log^2(x)$ out and then using L'Hospital after seeing that we get something like , $\infty - \infty$, but to no success.

Are there any smarter ways of going about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, it is not possible.  If $p\geq k$ then $\log(x)x^p$ dominates the other terms.  If $p<k$ then $\log^2(x)x^k$ dominates.  In either case the limit would be $\pm\infty$ since $k>0$.